# networkx How to loop through each cluster in graph

Tags: networkx

https://ibb.co/xKbTFK9

graph like:

```
1-8-2      90-22                78-75     
                     8-99

 214-2421-200-421
```

If i have a graph like that with many connected nodes in cluster as you see in the image, how can i iterate through each cluster in for loop like this:

```
for cluster in graph:

   .....do something with cluster....

   for node in cluster: 

         .....do something with node....
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this just once then do the following:

```
for connected_comp_subgraph in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G):
   ... do something ....
   for node in connected_comp_subgraph:
       ...do something...
```

If you just need a list of the nodes in each connected component rather than an actual graph, you can do

```
for connected_comp in nx.connected_components(G):
   ... do something ....
   for node in connected_comp:
       ...do something...
```

If you're going to do this multiple times and you don't want to recalculate these components each time, first do

```
connected_component_subgraphs = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G))
```

Without `list`, you get a "generator" which is more efficient memory/speed wise, but it calculates a component and as soon as you use it, it is completely forgotten.  Then it calculates the next one.  So if you want to save the components, store them in a list.